# Beginner question of lan and ubuntu server

Tags: networking

I am very new to network. I don't know what should I do in order to have highest security secure on my home network and internet.

I got a router have only one port and I connect it to hub and split it to 3 of my computers. 2 computers are windows ( Client ) which I use to browse internet and do some school work. And the other 1 computer is ubuntu-server and I ready to use it as web server and mysql server. If my server is been attacked, at least the others 2 of my computers wouldn't be affected.

So, any suggestion which is the best way for me to achieve it. I am a very new beginner to network so forgive me asking this kinds of silly question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your router has two ports, not one: one outside port and one inside port. To be secure, what you want to achieve is that no traffic originating from outside can travel in, unless you explicitly allow it to. You also want to achieve that traffic originating inside can travel out, *and* responses to it can travel back in and arrive at the originating computer.

If your router does NAT and offers port forwarding, then this is sufficient to achieve the above situation. Assign local IP addresses to the internal computers, and make the router NAT these to the outside. Local IP addresses are in the ranges 10.*, 192.168.* or 172.16-31.*. To expose your web server to the outside, set up a port forward of port 80 on the outside to port 80 on the server. Disallow any other port forwards, virtual hosts, or the like on your router.

This is not "the highest security" that you ask for. Security can always be improved on, but it's a good baseline.

Comment: Depending on the type of attack all three might be affected - a DDOS attack on your server would more than likely hamper internet connectivity on your 2 pcs

Comment: @pfeiffep Absolutely, but who is that DoS going to inconvenience? The OP states this is a *home* network, not a corporate web site. Who is interested in a denial of service attack on your home network? Sure, it *can* happen, but then ... what? Be real. Security is a relative asset, not an absolute. You should take measures in proportion to the size of the threats and/or the time you have on hand and/or the kicks you get out of setting up defenses. As I said, security can always be improved on, but this is a good baseline.

Answer (score 0):

There is a python program known as denyhosts http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/
this will make sure that if some one tries to login maliciously to your webserver he will automatically get blocked after 3-4 attempts (the number can be decided by you)

http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/securing-ssh.html

Once you install this learn about IPTABLES on Linux